# Is there an equivalent to assertFalse in nodeunit?

Tags: unit-testing, node.js, nodeunit

Using [nodeunit](https://github.com/caolan/nodeunit) is there an assert to check for false values?  Other testing frameworks have something like `assertFalse`, should I use something like:

```
test.ok(!shouldBeFalse());
```

or

```
test.equals(shouldBeFalse(), false);
```

Or is there a project that adds a false assertion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be sure only `boolean` `false` is matched than use [`strictEqual`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.2/api/assert.html#assert.strictEqual):

```
test.strictEqual(shouldBeFalse(), false)
```

Otherwise [`equal`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.2/api/assert.html#assert.equal) is ok too.